# QTP: Checking If an array of strings contains a value

Tags: vbscript, automated-tests, qtp

I am having trouble getting my test case to run correctly.

The problem is in the code below, the first if statement to be exact. QTP complains that an object is required

```
For j=Lbound(options) to Ubound(options)
    If options(j).Contains(choice) Then
        MsgBox("Found " & FindThisString & " at index " & _
        options.IndexOf(choice))
    Else
        MsgBox "String not found!"
    End If
Next
```

When I check the array I can see that it is populated correctly and 'j' is also the correct string.
Any help with this issue would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What are the contents of `options`? are these strings, some kind of test object (if so what kind)?

Comment: I am populating options like so:
`options(0) = "welcome"` which is strings if I am correct.
Its a fixed sized array.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Strings in VBScript are not objects, in that they do not have member functions. Searching for a substring should be done by using the [`InStr`](http://www.w3schools.com/vbscript/func_instr.asp) function.

```
For j=Lbound(options) to Ubound(options)
    If InStr(options(j), choice) <> 0 Then
        MsgBox("Found " & choice & " at index " & j
    Else
        MsgBox "String not found!"
    End If
Next
```

Comment: Ah yes. That explains the problems I was having. Thank you for your informative answer.

Comment: You implemented the Filter logic here, which searches for the string in the string instead of comparing it exactly.

Answer (score 16):

A concise way to check if an array of strings contains a value would be to combine the [Filter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e5s17ck1(v=vs.84).aspx) and [UBound](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fhx59d0t(v=vs.84).aspx) functions:

```
If Ubound(Filter(options, choice)) > -1 Then
    MsgBox "Found"
Else
    MsgBox "Not found!"
End If
```

Cons: you don't get the indexes where the elements are found

Pros: it's simple and you have the usual include and compare parameters to specify the matching criteria.

Comment: If I understand the docs correctly, the problem with this solution is that Filter will return all elements where choice is a substring. E.g. with an array containing "Dune", "Dunebug", "Blah", and choice = "Dune", it will return two items.

Answer (score 0):

Hi if you check exact String not sub-String in the array use StrComb because if use InStr then if array = "apple1" , "apple2" , "apple3" , "apple" and choice = "apple" then all will return pass for every array item.

```
Function CompareStrings ( arrayItems , choice )

For i=Lbound(arrayItems) to Ubound(arrayItems)

    ' 1 - for binary comparison "Case sensitive
    ' 0 - not case sensitive
    If StrComp(arrayItems(i), choice , 1) = 0 Then

    CompareStrings = True
    MsgBox("Found " & choice & " at index " & i

    Else

    CompareStrings = False
    MsgBox "String not found!"

    End If

Next

End Function
```

Comment: Instead of the (wrong!) magic numbers, the constants vbTextCompare/vbBinaryCompare should be used (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/05z4sfc7%28v=vs.84%29.aspx); setting the return value *in* the loop makes no sense.

Comment: Sorry.. You are right about the loop... but i have tried passing 0 and 1  it seems working fine..  i think instead of vbTextCompare/vbBinaryCompare 0 and 1 working fine..  Thank you

Comment: "working (fine)" is *not* a valid criterion for the quality of software. Don't be sorry, but correct your contribution.

Comment: Please Check : http://www.qtpworld.com/index.php?cid=36 , http://www.gcreddy.com/2010/04/vb-script-conditional-statements.html , http://www.w3schools.com/vbscript/func_strcomp.asp

Comment: Also Thank you for your point  "working (fine)" is not ok for the quality of software.. from the references i reached to a point that using 0 and 1 will work.. Thank you

Comment: Please if the above was wrong please let me know ... Because I'm using it in my entire test..

Answer (score 0):

```
Function CompareStrings ( arrayItems , choice )
For i=Lbound(arrayItems) to Ubound(arrayItems)

' 0 - for binary comparison "Case sensitive
' 1 - for text compare not case sensitive
If StrComp(arrayItems(i), choice , 0) = 0 Then

MsgBox("Found " & choice & " at index " & i

Else

MsgBox "String not found!"

End If

Next

End Function
```

Comment: now your function isn't a function and you still don't use the constants. Please delete this 'answer' and correct your previous one (containing the valuable pointer to StrComp()).